# How to check if ID exists in a row and echo some text if doesn't exist

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm using the following to select some photo, how do I incorporate 'IF EXISTS' so i can echo some text if no ID is found.

```
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE UID = '$ID' limit 30")
```

Comment: You mean mysql_num_rows($Result)==0  http://www.php.net/mysql_num_rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Result)) echo "You have photos!";
else echo "Dude... take some photos!";
```

Comment: You are gonna find rows if ID exists, so where ID doesn't exist that num_rows will just return nothing. So we have to check if the ID exists first.

Comment: Assuming you have a table with user IDs (UID), why not just query for a valid user id? `$Result = mysql_query("SELECT UID FROM users WHERE UID = '$ID' limit 1");`

Answer (score 0):

When no ID is found, the $Result will contain 0 values.

Now you can ask, how many values $Result contains with [mysql_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) function like this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($Result) == 0) echo "No Photo with $ID found";
else {
     while($photo = mysql_fetch_object($Result)) {
          //Here $photo contains a photo with the UID $ID
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i ended up doing.

```
<?php 
$data = preg_replace ('#[^0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['data']);
require_once 'db_conx.php';
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE pid = '$data' limit 30")
 or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result)){
$NoPhotos = (empty($row['photo'])) ?  'This Business Profile has no photos, you can send this business a message and ask them to upload some ' : '';
$Photos = (!empty($row['photo'])) ?  '<img width="32%" height="70" src="'.$row['photo'].'" class="ProPhotosID">' : '';
echo '
'.$NoPhotos.''.$Photos.'
';
}
?>
```